# I want to do pagination in my asp.net mvc application (very small application)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, pagination

Following code comes under Model.

```
**Products.cs**

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace UITest.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int productId { get; set; }
        public string productName { get; set; }
        public string productDescription { get; set; }
        public decimal productPriceOriginal { get; set; }
        public decimal productPriceSale { get; set; }
        public decimal productDiscount { get; set; }
        public DateTime discountStartDate { get; set; }
        public string discountStartDateString { get; set; }
        public DateTime discountEndDate { get; set; }
        public string discountEndDateString { get; set; }
        public int availableQty { get; set; }
        public List<string> productPictures { get; set; }
        public List<string> productPictures1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Following code comes under Controllers:

```
**HomeController.cs**

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using UITest.Models;

namespace UITest.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult ProductList()
        {
            List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
            //--------- 1
            Product p = new Product();
            p.productId = 1;
            p.productName = "Puzzle";
            p.productDescription = "Puzzle for children";
            p.productPriceOriginal = (decimal)500.0;
            p.productPriceSale = (decimal)450.00;
            p.productDiscount = 50;
            p.discountStartDate = new DateTime(2017, 8, 1);
            p.discountStartDateString = p.discountStartDate.ToShortDateString();
            p.discountEndDate = new DateTime(2017, 8, 31);
            p.discountEndDateString = p.discountEndDate.ToShortDateString();
            p.availableQty = 100;
            p.productPictures = new List<string>();
            //string imgPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/ProdPics/"), "Puzzle1.jpg");
            string imgPath = Url.Content("~\\ProdPics\\Puzzle1.jpg");   
            p.productPictures.Add(imgPath);
            p.productPictures1 = new List<string>();
            string imgPath1 = Url.Content("~\\ProdPics\\Puzzle2.jpg");   
            p.productPictures1.Add(imgPath1);
            products.Add(p);
            //--------- 2
            p = new Product();
            p.productId = 2;
            p.productName = "GWR Games";
            p.productDescription = "GWR Games for Children";
            p.productPriceOriginal = (decimal)600.0;
            p.productPriceSale = (decimal)540.00;
            p.productDiscount = 60;
            p.discountStartDate = new DateTime(2017, 8, 2);
            p.discountStartDateString = p.discountStartDate.ToShortDateString();
            p.discountEndDate = new DateTime(2017, 8, 31);
            p.discountEndDateString = p.discountEndDate.ToShortDateString();
            p.availableQty = 120;
            p.productPictures = new List<string>();
            imgPath = Url.Content("~\\ProdPics\\GBWR2016.jpg"); 
            p.productPictures.Add(imgPath);
            p.productPictures1 = new List<string>();
            imgPath1 = Url.Content("~\\ProdPics\\GBWR2017.jpg");
            p.productPictures1.Add(imgPath1);
            products.Add(p);
            //--------- 3
            p = new Product();
            p.productId = 3;
            p.productName = "Toy";
            p.productDescription = "Toy for Children";
            p.productPriceOriginal = (decimal)700.0;
            p.productPriceSale = (decimal)560.00;
            p.productDiscount = 140;
            p.discountStartDate = new DateTime(2017, 8, 3);
            p.discountStartDateString = p.discountStartDate.ToShortDateString();
            p.discountEndDate = new DateTime(2017, 8, 31);
            p.discountEndDateString = p.discountStartDate.ToShortDateString();
            p.availableQty = 150;
            p.productPictures = new List<string>();
            imgPath = Url.Content("~\\ProdPics\\Toy1.jpg"); 
            p.productPictures.Add(imgPath);
            p.productPictures1 = new List<string>();
            imgPath1 = Url.Content("~\\ProdPics\\Toy2.jpg");
            p.productPictures1.Add(imgPath1);
            products.Add(p);
            //--------- 4
            p = new Product();
            p.productId = 4;
            p.productName = "Mixer Grinder";
            p.productDescription = "Good Quality Mixer Grinder";
            p.productPriceOriginal = (decimal)17000.0;
            p.productPriceSale = (decimal)15000.00;
            p.productDiscount = 2000;
            p.discountStartDate = new DateTime(2017, 8, 3);
            p.discountStartDateString = p.discountStartDate.ToShortDateString();
            p.discountEndDate = new DateTime(2017, 8, 31);
            p.discountEndDateString = p.discountEndDate.ToShortDateString();
            p.availableQty = 140;
            p.productPictures = new List<string>();
            imgPath = Url.Content("~\\ProdPics\\MixerGrinder1.jpg"); 
            p.productPictures.Add(imgPath);
            p.productPictures1 = new List<string>();
            imgPath1 = Url.Content("~\\ProdPics\\MixerGrinder2.jpg");
            p.productPictures1.Add(imgPath1);
            products.Add(p);
            //--------- 5
            p = new Product();
            p.productId = 5;
            p.productName = "Football";
            p.productDescription = "Good Quality Football";
            p.productPriceOriginal = (decimal)900.0;
            p.productPriceSale = (decimal)600.00;
            p.productDiscount = 300;
            p.discountStartDate = new DateTime(2017, 8, 3);
            p.discountStartDateString = p.discountStartDate.ToShortDateString();
            p.discountEndDate = new DateTime(2017, 8, 31);
            p.discountEndDateString = p.discountEndDate.ToShortDateString();
            p.availableQty = 140;
            p.productPictures = new List<string>();
            imgPath = Url.Content("~\\ProdPics\\Football1.jpg");
            p.productPictures.Add(imgPath);
            p.productPictures1 = new List<string>();
            imgPath1 = Url.Content("~\\ProdPics\\Football2.jpg");
            p.productPictures1.Add(imgPath1);
            products.Add(p);
            //--------- 6
            p = new Product();
            p.productId = 6;
            p.productName = "Mobile";
            p.productDescription = "Cheapest SmartPhones";
            p.productPriceOriginal = (decimal)7000.0;
            p.productPriceSale = (decimal)4000.00;
            p.productDiscount = 3000;
            p.discountStartDate = new DateTime(2017, 8, 3);
            p.discountStartDateString = p.discountStartDate.ToShortDateString();
            p.discountEndDate = new DateTime(2017, 8, 31);
            p.discountEndDateString = p.discountEndDate.ToShortDateString();
            p.availableQty = 240;
            p.productPictures = new List<string>();
            imgPath = Url.Content("~\\ProdPics\\Mobile1.jpg"); 
            p.productPictures.Add(imgPath);
            p.productPictures1 = new List<string>();
            imgPath1 = Url.Content("~\\ProdPics\\Mobile2.jpg");
            p.productPictures1.Add(imgPath1);
            products.Add(p);
            return Json(products, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }


    }
}
```

Following Code comes under Home under Views.

```
    **index.cshtml**

    @{ 
        Layout = null;
    }

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/bootstrap-table.min.css" />
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/simplePagination.css" />
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.simplePagination.js"></script>

        <title>Test User Interface</title>
        <style>
            .prdImg {
                width: 100px;
            }
            .tableheight .fixed-table-container
            {
                width:490px;
            }
        </style>


    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12" style="text-align:center;">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="FetchProducts();">Show Products</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="divProdList">

        </div>
        <div class="container">

            <table id="tableproduct" data-height="450">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th data-field="productId">Product Id</th>
                        <th data-field="productName">Product Name</th>
                        <th data-field="productDescription">Product Description</th>
                        <th data-field="productPriceOriginal">Product Price Original</th>
                        <th data-field="productPriceSale">Product Price Sale</th>
                        <th data-field="productDiscount">Product Discount</th>
                        @*<th data-field="discountStartDate">Discount Start Date</th>*@
                        <th data-field="discountStartDateString">Discount Start Date</th>
                        @*<th data-field="discountEndDate">Discount End Date</th>*@
                        <th data-field="discountEndDateString">Discount End Date</th>
                        <th data-field="availableQty">Available Quantity</th>
                        <th data-field="productPictures" data-formatter="imageFormatter">Product Pictures</th>
                        <th data-field="productPictures1" data-formatter="imageFormatter">Product Pictures</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>

        </div>




        <script>
            function FetchProducts() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/ProductList',
                    type: "POST",
                    success: ShowProductList,
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        alert(xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }

            function imageFormatter(value, row) {
                return '<img class="prdImg" src="' + value + '" />';
            }


            function ShowProductList(response) {
                //var prodList = JSON.stringify(response);
                //$('#divProdList').html(prodList);
                var mydata = response;

                $('#tableproduct').bootstrapTable({
                    data:mydata
                });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Question: How to do pagination? I want to apply pagination and want to show three pictures in page 1 and rest three pictures in page 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
**HomeController.cs**

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using UITest.Models;

namespace UITest.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public int PageSize = 3;

        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
            products = Products();
            ViewBag.totalPage = (products.Count() + PageSize - 1) / PageSize;

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ProductList(string pageNumber)
        {
            List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
            products = Products();

            var page = Convert.ToInt32(pageNumber);
            var skip = PageSize * (page - 1);
            var productPage = products.OrderBy(x => x.productId)
                .Skip(skip)
                .Take(PageSize)
                .ToArray();

            return Json(productPage, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }


        public List<Product> Products()
        {

            List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
            //--------- 1
            Product p = new Product();
            p.productId = 1;
            p.productName = "Puzzle";
            p.productDescription = "Puzzle for children";
            p.productPriceOriginal = (decimal)500.0;
            p.productPriceSale = (decimal)450.00;
            p.productDiscount = 50;
            p.discountStartDate = new DateTime(2017, 8, 1);
            p.discountStartDateString = p.discountStartDate.ToShortDateString();
            p.discountEndDate = new DateTime(2017, 8, 31);
            p.discountEndDateString = p.discountEndDate.ToShortDateString();
            p.availableQty = 100;
            p.productPictures = new List<string>();
            //string imgPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/ProdPics/"), "Puzzle1.jpg");
            string imgPath = Url.Content("~\\ProdPics\\Puzzle1.jpg");   //Server.MapPath(".\\ProdPics\\Puzzle1.jpg");//Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(@"~\ProdPics\Puzzle1.jpg"));
            p.productPictures.Add(imgPath);
            p.productPictures1 = new List<string>();
            string imgPath1 = Url.Content("~\\ProdPics\\Puzzle2.jpg");
            p.productPictures1.Add(imgPath1);
            products.Add(p);

            //--------- 2
            p = new Product();
            p.productId = 2;
            p.productName = "GWR Games";
            p.productDescription = "GWR Games for Children";
            p.productPriceOriginal = (decimal)600.0;
            p.productPriceSale = (decimal)540.00;
            p.productDiscount = 60;
            p.discountStartDate = new DateTime(2017, 8, 2);
            p.discountStartDateString = p.discountStartDate.ToShortDateString();
            p.discountEndDate = new DateTime(2017, 8, 31);
            p.discountEndDateString = p.discountEndDate.ToShortDateString();
            p.availableQty = 120;
            p.productPictures = new List<string>();
            imgPath = Url.Content("~\\ProdPics\\GBWR2016.jpg"); //Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/ProdPics/"), "GBWR2016.jpg");
            p.productPictures.Add(imgPath);
            p.productPictures1 = new List<string>();
            imgPath1 = Url.Content("~\\ProdPics\\GBWR2017.jpg");
            p.productPictures1.Add(imgPath1);
            products.Add(p);

            //--------- 3
            p = new Product();
            p.productId = 3;
            p.productName = "Toy";
            p.productDescription = "Toy for Children";
            p.productPriceOriginal = (decimal)700.0;
            p.productPriceSale = (decimal)560.00;
            p.productDiscount = 140;
            p.discountStartDate = new DateTime(2017, 8, 3);
            p.discountStartDateString = p.discountStartDate.ToShortDateString();
            p.discountEndDate = new DateTime(2017, 8, 31);
            p.discountEndDateString = p.discountStartDate.ToShortDateString();
            p.availableQty = 150;
            p.productPictures = new List<string>();
            imgPath = Url.Content("~\\ProdPics\\Toy1.jpg");    // Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/ProdPics/"), "Toy1.jpg");
            p.productPictures.Add(imgPath);
            p.productPictures1 = new List<string>();
            imgPath1 = Url.Content("~\\ProdPics\\Toy2.jpg");
            p.productPictures1.Add(imgPath1);
            products.Add(p);

            //--------- 4
            p = new Product();
            p.productId = 4;
            p.productName = "Mixer Grinder";
            p.productDescription = "Good Quality Mixer Grinder";
            p.productPriceOriginal = (decimal)17000.0;
            p.productPriceSale = (decimal)15000.00;
            p.productDiscount = 2000;
            p.discountStartDate = new DateTime(2017, 8, 3);
            p.discountStartDateString = p.discountStartDate.ToShortDateString();
            p.discountEndDate = new DateTime(2017, 8, 31);
            p.discountEndDateString = p.discountEndDate.ToShortDateString();
            p.availableQty = 140;
            p.productPictures = new List<string>();
            imgPath = Url.Content("~\\ProdPics\\MixerGrinder1.jpg");     // Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/ProdPics/"), "Toy1.jpg");
            p.productPictures.Add(imgPath);
            p.productPictures1 = new List<string>();
            imgPath1 = Url.Content("~\\ProdPics\\MixerGrinder2.jpg");
            p.productPictures1.Add(imgPath1);
            products.Add(p);

            //--------- 5
            p = new Product();
            p.productId = 5;
            p.productName = "Football";
            p.productDescription = "Good Quality Football";
            p.productPriceOriginal = (decimal)900.0;
            p.productPriceSale = (decimal)600.00;
            p.productDiscount = 300;
            p.discountStartDate = new DateTime(2017, 8, 3);
            p.discountStartDateString = p.discountStartDate.ToShortDateString();
            p.discountEndDate = new DateTime(2017, 8, 31);
            p.discountEndDateString = p.discountEndDate.ToShortDateString();
            p.availableQty = 140;
            p.productPictures = new List<string>();
            imgPath = Url.Content("~\\ProdPics\\Football1.jpg");// Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/ProdPics/"), "Toy1.jpg");
            p.productPictures.Add(imgPath);
            p.productPictures1 = new List<string>();
            imgPath1 = Url.Content("~\\ProdPics\\Football2.jpg");
            p.productPictures1.Add(imgPath1);
            products.Add(p);

            //--------- 6
            p = new Product();
            p.productId = 6;
            p.productName = "Mobile";
            p.productDescription = "Cheapest SmartPhones";
            p.productPriceOriginal = (decimal)7000.0;
            p.productPriceSale = (decimal)4000.00;
            p.productDiscount = 3000;
            p.discountStartDate = new DateTime(2017, 8, 3);
            p.discountStartDateString = p.discountStartDate.ToShortDateString();
            p.discountEndDate = new DateTime(2017, 8, 31);
            p.discountEndDateString = p.discountEndDate.ToShortDateString();
            p.availableQty = 240;
            p.productPictures = new List<string>();
            imgPath = Url.Content("~\\ProdPics\\Mobile1.jpg");      // Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/ProdPics/"), "Toy1.jpg");
            p.productPictures.Add(imgPath);
            p.productPictures1 = new List<string>();
            imgPath1 = Url.Content("~\\ProdPics\\Mobile2.jpg");
            p.productPictures1.Add(imgPath1);
            products.Add(p);

            return products;
        }
    }
}

**Index.cshtml**

@{ 
    Layout = null;
    int totalPage = ViewBag.totalPage;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/bootstrap-table.min.css" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
    @*<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/simplePagination.css" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.simplePagination.js"></script>*@

    <title>Test User Interface</title>
    <style>
        .prdImg {
            width: 100px;
        }
        /*.tableheight .fixed-table-container
        {
            width:490px;
        }*/

        .divheight
        {
            margin-top:30px;
        }
        /*.lastCol {
            width: 149px !important;
        }*/
    </style>


</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="text-align:center;">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="FetchProducts(1);">Show Products</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="divProdList" class="divheight">

    </div>

    <div class="container" style="display:none">
        <table id="tableproduct" data-height="450">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-field="productId">Product Id</th>
                    <th data-field="productName">Product Name</th>
                    <th data-field="productDescription">Product Description</th>
                    <th data-field="productPriceOriginal">Product Price Original</th>
                    <th data-field="productPriceSale">Product Price Sale</th>
                    <th data-field="productDiscount">Product Discount</th>
                    @*<th data-field="discountStartDate">Discount Start Date</th>*@
                    <th data-field="discountStartDateString">Discount Start Date</th>
                    @*<th data-field="discountEndDate">Discount End Date</th>*@
                    <th data-field="discountEndDateString">Discount End Date</th>
                    <th data-field="availableQty">Available Quantity</th>
                    <th data-field="productPictures" data-formatter="imageFormatter">Product Pictures</th>
                    <th data-field="productPictures1" data-formatter="imageFormatter">Product Pictures</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table> 
        <ul class="pagination">
            @for (int i = 1; i <= totalPage; i++)
            {
                <li><a href="#">@i</a></li>
            }
        </ul>

    </div>

    <script>
        $(".pagination li a").click(function () {
            var pageNo = $(this).text();
            FetchProducts(pageNo);
        });

        function FetchProducts(pageNo) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/ProductList',
                type: "POST",
                data: { pageNumber: pageNo },
                datatype: 'json',
                success: ShowProductList,
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
        }


        function imageFormatter(value, row) {
            return '<img class="prdImg" src="' + value + '" />';
        }


        function ShowProductList(response) {

            //var prodList = JSON.stringify(response);
            //$('#divProdList').html(prodList);

            var mydata = response;
            $('#tableproduct').bootstrapTable();
            $('#tableproduct').bootstrapTable('load', mydata);
            $(".container").show();
        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the datatable plugin. Since you said it is a small application (limited data), it makes sense to have client pagination than server side. Look at the https://datatables.net/. You basically have to just include the library js and css, and call $('#tableproduct').datatable(); in your script.

Comment: What should i do after adding library js and css and calling $(#tableproduct').datatable(); ? Can you please check my code and let me know what to add and where to add? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Look here @Saakey7 https://jsfiddle.net/dyx1kc3g/. 1) Add Jquery, 2) Add dataTable plugin js and css, 3) Append your data to your table (just write a for loop over your data and add rows manually), 4) Call $('#tableproduct').datatable();

Comment: it's solved bro. :) but thank you for your idea.. will keep in mind for future.